# Minimum Vertex Cover variation

Tags: graph-theory

In Graph theory, a minimum vertex cover is the smallest set of vertices that covers all edges.

[image: Minimum Vertex Cover]

In this diagram, the minimum Vertex cover would require both 3 and either 1 or 2 (to cover the edge between 1 and 2).

Is there an equivalent set of minimum vertex required to connect at least once to all other vertices. 
[image: Limited Minimum Vertex]

In this diagram, only 3 would be required, as it connects to edges that connect to all other Vertices.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set

Comment: That's the answer. If you submit it as an answer I'll mark it as such. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of vertices you are looking for is called a *dominating set* and the size of the smallest dominating set is the *dominating number* of the graph. These have been extensively researched and a quick Google search will yield plenty of hits.